# Write second table of SP output to a CSV file via BCP

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, bcp

Im running SQL Server 2008 on winows server 2008 and I have a stored proc that outputs some information about a product entity with the inout as a product Id. 
It outputs  a reecord to represent the product information followed by a second table full of orders.
Im wondering if there is any way to call the stored proc and write the orders data to a CSV file from the command shell?

The other alternative is to try this using a custom written application and a data reader but I dont realy want to go down this route.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the SQLCMD command-line utility to do this. It's a complex tool to use; the BOL entry can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx), and if necessary a bit of googling should turn up the odd tutorial that goes over the basics.